# Mongodb find() result to file

Tags: mongodb

How can I save my output from db.xxx.find() to a flat file. As a quick search in stackoverflow, most of the answers are suggest use

```
mongo 127.0.0.1/db --eval "var c = db.collection.find(); while(c.hasNext()) {printjson(c.next())}" >> test.txt
```

or

```
mongo 127.0.0.1/db script.js >> test.txt
```

But I need to do the authentication and other stuffs before doing find(). And I need to do it inside the mongo console. Any suggestions?

Comment: If none of the other suggestions would work for you, you'll need to write the export using your favorite programming language. Or, look at using `mongoexport` tool with the `json` option.

Comment: mongoexport -- good suggestion @WiredPrairie